# json_rpc_call solo mining with bitcoin running on Windows 7 for antminer

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, solo-mining, antminer

I setup BitcoinD on a Windows 7 PC.  I configured for defaults except user/pw and `rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0`. I have also tried `192.168.1.*` with no luck.

I ultimately want to use an Antminer to connect to it for solo mining, but cannot use it for anything other than mining on the same computer on which it is running.

WORKING: using bfgminer with the following command line:

```
bfgminer-5.0.0-win64\bfgminer-5.0.0-win64\bfgminer.exe -o 127.0.0.1:8332 -u rpcuser -p rpcpw
```

NOT WORKING:

```
bfgminer-5.0.0-win64\bfgminer-5.0.0-win64\bfgminer.exe -o 192.168.1.123:8332 -u rpcuser -p rpcpw
```

The only difference is the IP address where 123 is my IP.

Error: "json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds"

I looked at firewall and it has entries for "Bitcoin Core"

`netstat -a` output:

```
0.0.0.0:8332
0.0.0.0:8333
127.0.0.1:8332
192.168.1.123:8333
```

Antminer says pool is dead.

How do I get another computer or Antminer, on my network, to connect for solo mining?

Comment: Try `192.168.1.0/24` which is the correct CIDR subnet mask notation for `192.168.1.*`. Also `server=1`.

Comment: That is working better but what BFGminer is hashing on the same computer using the computer's IP address, it is giving these errors:
Stratum connect failed with TLS to pool 0: could not resolve host: 192.168.1.123

Comment: With windows firewall off, I still cannot connect with Antminer.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: have you try to solo mine with creating your own pool with coiniumserv or Nomp ? ? i made success solo mining with them on windows

Answer (score 0):

BFGminer needs to use stratum (bitcoin core doesn't)

Add --stratum-port=3333 to your bat file with 192.168.1.123:8333 then point your antminer at 192.168.1.123:3333

Ta. 3KMxGyAFJA9zFnaXfPEkrjoLozXcZz8FH4